# Element type is invalid

Tags: react-native

I often receive following. Is there a straightforward way of tracking down the offending component?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no really easy method of finding out which component is causing the error after long changes.

This usually means you added curly braces for the import of a component that has a default export, or forgot to add the curly braces for an element that doesn't have the default export.

What I like to do to prevent it is save+test every time I add something new.

Comment: Curly brackets of default export really was a unnoticeable bug for me, thanks